# Error al enviar base64 desde android a Lumen/Laravel

Tags: php, android, lumen

Estoy enviando información de android a lumen, mi problema es al intentar enviar una cade de base64, ya que no llega completa y se envia cortada.

Android

```
String base64;
base64 = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(),Base64.NO_WRAP | Base64.URL_SAFE);
```

Retrofit Model

```
ReportRequest report = new ReportRequest("2000, -2000", description.getText().toString(), 100,  base64);
```

Lumen:

```
$data = $request->json()->all();
return response()->json(array('message' => json_encode( $data['image'] )), 200);
```

Despues de enviar esta información a traves de retrofit la respuestas es la siguiente:

```
D/Response: "9j_4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD_2wBDACAWGBwYFCAcGhwkIiAmMFA0MCwsMGJGSjpQdGZ6eHJmcG6AkLicgIiuim5woNqirr7EztDOfJri8uDI8LjKzsb_2wBDASIkJDAqMF40NF7GhHCExsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbxxxEsQAAIBAwMCBAIJAgQBCwMCBwECEQADIRIxQVFhBBMicTKBBSNCUpGhscHRFOEzYnLw8QYVJDQ1Q1NzgpKiVGOTsiUWdKPCNkRF_8QAGQEBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQF_8QAIhEBAQEBAQADAQADAQEBAAAAAAERAhIDITETBDJBIhRR_9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwDyYxWEE81udjQHIFIwanG2_FA5zW6GtoETRIGoZrSRJA2rH3rKA_SsimNqXdqOsgxPNRFKmaaRmtiSaiMJ6Vic1iZ2FDJ4qgb_AIVitMBAnqxxy_EM1VyCpzUgM9q1zBitLEtpHIrr8PhRIHtXKN5k102mG56xXPpvkLgggwfashgEU5HMHapE5npvWJ9tKzApWYzkVu5mljU0d66xkR8UTQYyxMmiwjM-9IuWxtSoqq4FHSVPxxxxs6zhDnNTzBmqQelTfrUUjZB70VmB1FAnAgg1kInfitYQwEHmqdKnMcmn5gE0aMQAN6wBgmK0SIOetNpkQazQgM43pWBGwxTbZoESDFGUdDdKckAROaIO2dt6WNzBknFUS2NMvzp2gHMRQkYE5ognbahH51xxxxTGc0TJ2pRkYJNNBCxvRuAJmYFU1TwIpZHuaynEkUZMVAyCDScb0VyJmg3IOKi6QmOKWCaYxxNJ5Dbm4K1glqzM0Zx1qv9OvN0U3lWh_3poOYsJAkU_2SeKc27IafNasTYI3JFaE7YBaI_OiBJIp9VlBIBpfOt7ohNbjHkpULOIpYkbULl0PiINPsBVTACiIxQgcGmA5zJoaYOJrFbg561gCOxxxKRd5App7VKNpmsTGIxQLE7g0wTnNZAU94osTp3rFZJIjtSs_UCooJaDcZmrpb0iCIo22UgQBTyFEVmriRJGJqbyxpnbJMbCk1gYBFaiaVx0NR2O5qpbcxmpE8wJrrGWkkgRg0DgjImsDAFZyCOJFUXQoAmqECQT0qNgHWCTNdJX05NZtWJaoyRWAGkHBrXAVWpgwBkYrUNMY3FG2ogyKXfMUSSIEHbbFUYdKKtMYzSTDTnFFXyTAihFIoQOlbUCSSaGvvWLFc2qZnmh9rajpmB86EyZrTnTwcTReABk5xVkv6icVO8RrAHFVWEkVj06UqSD2G1YmTiajNGBHehGc0SaXmohgMTW6CjbzitFRBz1oRHWtMUuaoP7Ucd6Xb2onGKoPFLcGZzQoOTMSe1VqGtxmek10KBBHM1C0MT2NUWdtuhrn06cnkEHNSKnIEZ2xxPzqKmWIzVBEbnakVfVztXWMhcEEZJo7DFG6JYAClKkQKVF1nan0wJqKuBBJFU1E5msIx23pSuJmmyYxR0wMg1FczqYpEHMGukxUivq6da3DDETsBBozB4pUYggb0zKd896Kad962smSJo2LepZkzFKq6SQamBoBmpucxn5U5MCpyJIkmohTnFaTInigc4IrDcyaqMQYrRyTTsAeeKykQARIIohVgnJrQdXagfiJ261i3sZopwZMgRRgDANIjSZIqk4iDRdbQd4BoEGDxTqe1B5OQOKqVNG4p3MDfNTAIJMUYO88VCJneJNMSVWZEUj_FzTp6xEbUwdHh4dNh3pmthcqT-FQtsbeJjpVGvAzBmKKYJPIz2rf07MTBWptqMAE_jRI0tALfjQdH9OMyyis3h0KAeYBUZETB_GqKoKxpHvSKkPD2laTeBq5Phogt_Ncly0FuER
```

Lo cual si se dan cuenta no cierra las comillas, es decir esta llegando incompleto. Ya intente enviarlo como `String b64 = "mi_imagen_b64";` lo cual llega perfectamente.

¿Alguien sabe que esta ocurriendo?, porque esta cortando mi cadena o en todo caso, porque no esta cerrando las comillas?